# Angular - display default value before result of | async

Tags: angular, angular6

How can I display `-` until the result of `$futureCredit` returns?

```html
    <span [innerText]="'-'">
      {{ futureCredit$ | async | currency:'EUR'}}
    </span>
```

I tried with innerText but the result of the async doesn't override the `-`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
<span>
  {{ (futureCredit$ | async | currency:'EUR') || '-'}}
</span>
```

Comment: This is not working, `-` is the value regardless to the result of the `futureCredit$`

Comment: If the return value of the observable is `0` or otherwise 'falsy', the OR operator still matches. To avoid this (at least with numbers), add the `DecimalPipe`(https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe). For example: `{{ (entity.relatedRecords | async | number: '1.0-0' ) || 'loading...' }}`

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the ngIf else directive.

```
<span *ngIf="futureCredit$ | async as credit; else default">
 {{ credit  | currency:'EUR' }}
</span>  
<ng-template #default>
<span> - <span>
</ng-template>
```

it works for this case but if futureCredit would give back a value that is falsy it will still render the else case.

In this case i would use a custom rxjs pipe:

```
// invokes a callback upon subscription
export function prepare<T>(
  callback: () => void,
): (source: Observable<T>) => Observable<T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> =>
    defer(() => {
      callback();
      return source;
    });
}
```

which you could use like :

---------------------------TS-----------------------------

```
startFutureVal$ = new Subject<boolean>();
futureVal$.pipe(prepare(() => startFutureVal$.next(true))
                   ,tap(() => startFutureVal$.next(false)))
```

---------------------------HTML---------------------------

```
<span *ngIf="futureVal$ | async as val"> val </span>
<span *ngIf="startFutureVal$ | async">
  -
</span>
```

Of course this is all a bit overkill for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Solution provided in first part of LeKeque's comment is enough to solve the stated problem. I have solved similiar problem by this solution.

Solution by LeKeque:

```
<span *ngIf="futureCredit$ | async as credit; else default">
 {{ credit  | currency:'EUR' }}
</span>  
<ng-template #default>
<span> - <span>
</ng-template>
```